# Map URL to file on loca lsystem

Tags: java, spring, servlets, mapping

I want to redirect a URL to a file on my server, such that when that URL is opened, it fetches the particular pdf file from the server and opens it on the browser.
It works on a client server interface. 
Please help me what way can I redirect my URL to a particular file on my server.

Comment: you could try `<mvc:resources mapping="/pdf/example.pdf" location="file:/temp/example.pdf" />` if you are using spring mvc

Answer (score 0):

```
new File(path).toURI().toURL();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, let assume you have following url:

```
http://somesiste.bla/render?path=/dirx/hello1.pdf
```

If the PDF file is located in your application WAR file,  And you WAR file look like this

```
WAR
 -- index.jspx
 -- WEB-INF
    --web.xml
 -- data
    --dirx
      --hello01.pdf
      --hello02.pdf
```

Then this is really easy just forward to the right file in your app

```
public void forwardToPdf( HttpServletRequest request,    HttpServletResponse response, String path ) throws ServletException, IOException
   {
   RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher= request.getRequestDispatcher("/data/" +path) ;                 
   requestDispatcher.forward( request, response ) ;
   }

// Get the parameter and pass it on
String path = getParameter("path");
forwardToPdf(request, response, path);
```

But If the file is located outside your application lets say

```
C:\data\
```

The you can't just redirect to that file, what you have to do is read that file in and render it to the user

Just a small utility for doing that.

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    public class FileDownloadHelper {

    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE_EXCEL ="application/vnd.ms-excel";
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE_WORD_DOCUMENT ="application/doc";
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE_MS_WORD ="application/msword";
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE_PDF ="application/pdf";

    public static final String CONTENT_DISPOSITION_INLINE ="inline";
    public static final String CONTENT_DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT ="attachment";

    public void write(HttpServletResponse response, byte[] data, String contentType, String outputFileName, String contentDisposition){
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        ServletOutputStream sos = null;
        try {   
            sos = response.getOutputStream();
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

            if(data != null){

                response.setContentType(contentType);
                long contentLength = data.length;
                /* IE requires the following for pdf files */
                response.setBufferSize((int)contentLength);
                //This enables us to show estimated download time
                response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(contentLength));
                // inline=forces to use a viewer  attachment=show save dialog            
                //response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + outputFileName + "\"");
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition+"; filename=\"" + outputFileName + "\"");
                // These set of headers need to be here for this to work with IE  with servlet security
                // This will prevent catching of the results
                response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");

                sos.write(data);
            }else{
                sendResponse404(response);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            close(sos);
        }   
    }



    /**
     * Helper method to send 404 - Resource not found message
     * @param response
     */
    private void sendResponse404(HttpServletResponse response) {
        //Resource not found
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        try {           
            response.getOutputStream().write("Resource not found".getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to take care of cleanup
     * @param resource to close
     */
    private  void close(Closeable resource) {
        if (resource != null) {
            try {
                resource.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And then your can simply use it as follow

```
// Force browser to download the resource
    FileDownloadHelper download = new FileDownloadHelper();
    download.write(response, readFileToBytes(pathToFileOnYourFileSystem), FileDownloadHelper.CONTENT_TYPE_PDF,"OUTPUTFILENA.PDF", 
    FileDownloadHelper.CONTENT_DISPOSITION_ATTACHMENT
```

I hope this helps and make sense. There are couple things missing such as 'readFileToBytes' and getting parameters but this should get you going.